# passing/parsing PCL code to word or excel

Tags: c#, printing, printer-control-language

Is it possible to convert the pcl code I have to a readable version in word or excl or any thing else?

Are there any DLL's to perform it.

Comment: It is already readable.  Best thing to do is to *print* it to a Hewlett Packard printer or plotter to see what emerges.

Comment: I tried doing that, I called this PCL file through a .Net Program and was trying to print the original file....but it gave me all the garbage data of the actual PCL file...I want the original readable format data back at the printer........if I input a PCL file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what driver created the PCL the data may not be that parsable.  You could talk to the guys at [Pagetech](http://www.pagetech.com/) as they have some tools for conversion.